# How to label points in kml polygon file using R

Tags: r, raster, kml, google-earth

I can create a kml polygon (circles for different sites) file using R, but when I open the file in Google Earth, the site names that go with each site are not there.  Here is my code to make circles with 15 mile radii surrounding points in South Dakota.

```
make_GeodesicBuffer <- function(pts, width){
 # A) Construct buffers as points at given distance and bearing ---------------
 dg <- seq(from = 0, to = 360, by = 1)

 # Construct equidistant points defining circle shapes (the "buffer points")
 buff.XY <- geosphere::destPoint(p = pts, 
                              b = rep(dg, each = length(pts)), 
                              d = width)

 # B) Make SpatialPolygons -------------------------------------------------

 # Group (split) "buffer points" by id
 buff.XY <- as.data.frame(buff.XY)
 id  <- rep(1:dim(pts)[1], times = length(dg))
 lst <- split(buff.XY, id)

 # Make SpatialPolygons out of the list of coordinates
 poly   <- lapply(lst, sp::Polygon, hole = FALSE)
 polys  <- lapply(list(poly), sp::Polygons, ID = NA)
 spolys <- sp::SpatialPolygons(Srl = polys, 
                            proj4string = CRS(as.character("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 
 +datum=WGS84")))

 # Disaggregate (split in unique polygons)
 spolys <- sp::disaggregate(spolys)
 return(spolys)}

points = data.frame(id = c('ATRS2','BFMS2','BKMS2'),
                lat = c(45.5,44.3,45.4),
                lon = c(-103.3,-96.9,-96.8))

# Miles to meters conversion
mile2meter <- function(x){
x * 1609.344}

TO_1to4_buf_15miles <- make_GeodesicBuffer(as.matrix(points), width = mile2meter(15))

raster::KML(TO_1to4_buf_15miles, filename =
'F:\\Siting\\TO_1to4_buf_15miles.kml',overwrite=TRUE)
```

This works and the circles show up nicely in Google Earth.  But how do I get the site names (ATRS2, BFMS2, BKMS2) to show up in Google Earth in the tree structure for each circle in the kml file that gets written out?  Thank you.

Comment: Can you share a copy or sample of the KML output?

Comment: Also, can you clarify whether you are trying to add Labels (on the map), or just names in the list view (in the Places panel on the left)?  Finally, I don't know R, so can't read your code, but I see mention of "RASTER" in there, so are you generating individual polygon features for each circle (vector data), or is the output one or more Image Overlays (raster data)... that's one of the reasons it would help to see your KML output.

Comment: I don't know how I would share a copy of the kml file itself, but I'm trying to add names in the list view (first column of the points data frame).  The output in the KML is 3 different polygon features (circles).  The raster package is used because it has a nice function called "KML", that easily writes out kml files.  Finally, the code for creating the buffered points should be: TO_1to4_buf_15miles <- make_GeodesicBuffer(as.matrix(points[,2:3]), width = mile2meter(15)).  Thank you.

Comment: Ok, if you're just trying to add names in the list view, then you need to make sure that each <Placemark> tag ends up containing a <name>...</name> tag with the desired text.  Hopefully others can suggest how to implement that in R.  Searching for "r export KML name" gave me a few results that look potentially useful.  As for sharing KML files, I've seen folks do it a number of ways... if it's small enough, you can paste the XML into a code block in your question, or if it's too big then you need somewhere to upload/host the file, and then provide a link.  Google drive is one option.